# Is tristate buffer power consumption high?

Tags: power, circuit-design, buffer, tri-state

I have 2 questions about tristate buffer.

1. Is there any problem with using many tristate buffers in circuit design? is tristate buffer power consumption very high?
2. Is it a good solution to replace a transistor and use it as a tristate element in such situation?

Comment: You can add more details to your question as on what are you trying to achieve and what have you done till now on this, what is your understanding and how someone can help you. Its a community trying to help each other only when needed and not when wanted by anyone.

Answer (score 2):

1. A tristate buffer should have the same power consumption as any other buffer when enabled. It should have zero power consumption when disabled.
2. Show a schematic for your proposed solution so we know what you are talking about.

You can add a schematic in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip.
Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: my problem is about the power consumption. i dont know how many tri-state buffer is good and how many can make a problem such as high power consumption.

Comment: What do you not understand about my answer?

Comment: your answer was useful but my problem is generally about the number of tri-state buffers that can be used in logical design? according to the our teacher it is better to avoid tri-state buffer in design because of high power consumption. but if our circuit needs tri-state buffer, what do we do? how many can we use?

Comment: Tri-state buffers are the basis of busses.  How many do you need?

Comment: Ask your teacher the reason for saying that. You may have misunderstood something. You can have as many tristate buffers as you require provided no more than one is driving each bus line. All the others will consume no power as I have explained already.